# Pointers with increment and decrement operators

Tags: c

In general, when the assignment operator is there left operand should be a variable and not an expression but when I am making left side an expression using pointers, the code is not producing any error.

Jdoodle online compiler/C

It should throw an error however successful compilation is there.

https://www.jdoodle.com/c-online-compiler

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int x = 30, *y, *z;

    y = &x; // Assume address of x is 1000 and integer is 4 byte size */
    z = y;
    *y++ = *z++;
    x++;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: _I am making left side an expression using pointers_ There is nothing wrong with this, you are dereferencing the pointer and incrementing the value where the pointer points to. What is your problem?

Comment: What is your question? `It should throw an error` - no, it shouldn't, it's ok.

Comment: "Sum of x+y = 35"  which result are you expecting?

Comment: @xxxvodnikxxx That's the default template code when you visit that site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose, address of `x` is `1000` and `sizeof(int) = 4` (for a `32-bit` compiler), then when you evaluate the expression:

```
 *y++=*z++;
```

Address of z is incremented

**(Since, post-increment(x++) has higher precedence than ( *x ) )**

but before that  **rvalue** i.e. address stored by `z` is assigned to pointer `y`.
    After that only increment of address and dereferencing is taking place.
    Similar is the case for `*y++`, first address is assigned, post-increment occurs and is then dereferenced. If you are confused about lvalue to be a variable, it is not necessary E.g. : adding a statement like in your code after initializing the pointer with a valid address 
 
**`*y++;`**
 is also correct and will not flag any error.

Answer (score 2):

The left operand of an assignment does not have to be a variable. For example, the following assignments should and do work perfectly fine (and I assume you know that and just misspoke):

```
array[index] = value;
*ptr = value;
```

I think what's confusing you about `*y++ = *z++;` is that you think that it's assigning to the result of an increment operation, which would indeed make no sense. But that's not the precedence of that expression: `*y++` is equivalent to `*(y++)`, not `(*y)++`. So you're dereferencing the result of `y++` and then assign a value to that dereferenced memory location, just as if you had written:

```
int *ptr = y++;
*ptr = *z++;
```

Answer (score 2):

> In general, when the assignment operator is there left operand should
>   be a variable and not an expression ...

The left operand of an assignment operator is *always* an expression. The restriction is that it has to be an *lvalue*, which is (simplifying a bit) an expression that designates an object.

The simplest case of an lvalue is the name of a declared object/variable, so for example:

```
int n;
n = 42;
```

`n` is an expression, specifically an lvalue, that designates the object named `n`.

In your example, you have:

```
*y++ = *z++;
```

Operator precedence says that the `++` operator binds more tightly than the `*` operator, so this is equivalent to:

```
*(y++) = *(z++);
```

`y++` and `z++` are not values -- they're expressions that yield pointer values, but they don't designate any objects. But the unary `*` operator gives you an lvalue even when its operand is not an lvalue.  `y++` yields a pointer value, and `*(y++)` gives you the object that that pointer points to.

The C standard doesn't use the term "variable" in this sense. It talks about *objects*, which may or may not be declared objects with simple names. `an_object`, `*pointer_value`, `array[index]`, and `structure_object.member` all refer to objects and can appear on the left side of an assignment.

Answer (score 2):

> left operand should be a variable and not an expression

This is a misunderstanding. The term you are looking for is *lvalue*. This a C standard gibberish term originating from the term "left value". The definition of the term *lvalue* is roughly: an expression that designates an object.

The rules for the various operators discussed here are:

- The left operand of the assignment operators must always be a lvalue.
- The result of the unary `*` operator is defined to always be a lvalue, so you can use it as if it was an object, and we can assign to it.
- The result of the ++ operators however, is *not* an lvalue, so it cannot be used as the left operand of assignment.

Examples:

```
int x; int* y;

x = 5;   // Here x is both an object and an lvalue, so the code is valid
y = &x;  // y is both a (pointer) object and an lvalue, code is valid.
*y = 0;  // *y is an lvalue designating the object y, code is valid
y++ = 1; // y++ is not an lvalue, the code is invalid
```

As for why `*y++` works, it is just a matter of operator precedence. The ++ is applied first, but since it is postfix, the change doesn't take place until the end of the expression. So `*` is applied to `y` and the result is a lvalue.

Had you written `++*y = 0;` then operator associativity had caused the `*` to execute first, the result `*y` being an lvalue. And then when you use `++` on that lvalue, the result of ++ is not an lvalue so the code is invalid. `++*y` in itself is valid code, but it can't be the left operand of assignment.